# Displaying a value from three linked lists in Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list

in my Python program I work with lists, my list looks like this:
**List1=[[X1, X2, X3], [Y1, Y2, Y3]]**
I only want to display the value X1 from this list with Print.

I tried the following:
**print(List1[0])**
but X1,X2,X3 is displayed.
I only need the X1 displayed.

thanks for your help in advance

Comment: `print(List1[0][0]) `

Comment: It's called **nested list**, not *linked list*. Should make searching easier in the future.

Comment: ok Thank you for your help, I remember that with the nested list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print(List1[0][0])
```

List1[0] is displaying the first value of your list, which happen to also be a list

`List1=[[X1, X2, X3], [Y1, Y2, Y3]]` so `List1[0] = [X1, X2, X3]`

`List1[0][0]` means displaying the first value of the first value of your List1, ence in your case X1